# Join 2 tables to get all raws. Get all distinct join columns

Tags: sql, hive

I have 2 similar tables

```
CREATE TABLE arstel.b2b_join2(
id string
, name string
, col1 string
, col2 string
);
```

I fill them with data. First table.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE arstel.b2b_join1 VALUES
("1", "a", "a1", "a2")
, ("2", "b", "b1", "b2")
, ("3", "c", "c1", "c2")
, ("4", "d", "d1", "d2");
```

Secnd table

```
INSERT INTO TABLE arstel.b2b_join2 VALUES
("1", "a", "a11", "a22")
, ("2", "b", "b11", "b22")
, ("5", "e", "e11", "e22")
, ("6", "f", "f11", "f22");
```

My query

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN a.id = NULL THEN b.id ELSE a.id END AS id
, CASE WHEN a.name = NULL THEN b.name ELSE a.name END AS name
, a.col1
, a.col2
, b.col1
, b.col2
FROM arstel.b2b_join1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN arstel.b2b_join2 b
ON a.id = b.id AND a.name = b.name;
```

Return all values from table `a`, but doesn't return `id` and `name` from `b`

```
4       d       d1      d2      NULL    NULL
1       a       a1      a2      a11     a22
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    e11     e22
2       b       b1      b2      b11     b22
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    f11     f22
3       c       c1      c2      NULL    NULL
```

What I actually want is

```
4       d       d1      d2      NULL    NULL
1       a       a1      a2      a11     a22
5       e       NULL    NULL    e11     e22
2       b       b1      b2      b11     b22
6       f       NULL    NULL    f11     f22
3       c       c1      c2      NULL    NULL
```

How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't compare with `null`. Use `is null` or `is not null` instead.

The result you need can be achieved using `COALESCE`. It returns the first non-null value.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(a.id,b.id) AS id
, COALESCE(a.name,b.name) AS name
, a.col1
, a.col2
, b.col1
, b.col2
FROM arstel.b2b_join1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN arstel.b2b_join2 b
ON a.id = b.id AND a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: I actually thought about `is null` right after posting the question =) But didn't know about `coalesce`. Thanks